# eslint object-shorthand rule with no-undef rule

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, eslint

I created a new React(v15.6.1) project with `create-react-app`. This code

```
const Range = {
    Near, Far
}
```

makes ESlint inside VSCode report "'Near' is not defined. (no-undef)" (`Far` has the same error.)

The code compiles, but the error is a bit distracting.

Here's the `.eslintrc`

```
{
    "extends": "react-app",
    "rules": {
        "object-shorthand": [
            2,
            "always"
        ]
    }
}
```

Is there a way to use both [object-shorthand](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-shorthand) and [no-undef](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef)?

### Edit:

Sorry I misunderstood the shorthand literal:

```
> a = 3
3
> b = {a}
{ a: 3 }
```

That should demonstrate its usage.

Comment: Well, are `Near` and `Far` defined? Do you want to *disable* `no-undef`? Not sure I understand the issue.

Comment: No. I wish to use the "shorthand object  literal". Did I miss something?

Comment: The shorthand rule enforces the use of shorthand properties if possible. I.e. it will tell you to use `{foo}` instead of `{foo: foo}`. The code you posted however is indeed invalid though, because the variables `Near` and `Far` are not defined (i.e. the "no-undef" rule works as intended). Maybe you are misunderstanding how shorthand properties work. This is how they work: `var foo = 42; var obj = {foo};` is the same as `var foo = 42; var object = {foo: foo};` or `var obj = {foo: 42};`.

Comment: Thanks! Just visit the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) page. I thought it was a syntactic sugar for defining enum-like things.